# Discrete math: given an integer, there are no two integer x,y such that x>k/2 and y>k/2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

I wanted to ask if the use of quantifier in this proof were correct:

let $k$ be a positive integer. Then $\lnot \exists x,y$ that are integer and such that $x>k/2 \land y>k/2$ and $x+y=k$.

Proof by contradiction: suppose that two such integers $x,y$ existed. Then $x>k/2 \land y>k/2$ implies that $x+y>k/2+k/2$ but then $x+y>k$ and so $x+y=k$ would be false.

Therefore, it is true that $\lnot \exists x,y$ such that $x+y=k$ and $x>k/2 \land y>k/2$ and $x+y=k$.

Comment: An utterly correct proof by contradiction. In the last part you mentioned "x+y=k" twice. In the title, this crucial detail is missing.

Comment: Your header question is very misleading (and obviously wrong as stated).

Comment: The title claim is not correct. Just take $x=y=k$ for positive $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct.

Another way to think about it is $\dfrac{k}{2} = u$.

$x > u \land y > u \Rightarrow x + y > 2u \Rightarrow x + y > k$